# filter values of one dataframe if present and not exists in another dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have two data sets details and reference details. 
Details

#### code     date    location temperature

```
1      1-1-19    blr      30


2      1-2-18    up       33


3      1-2-18    dlh      25
```

refrenceDetails

#### code    date       location

1          1-1-19     blr

2          1-2-18      up

I would like to filter records from details dataset as valid details if code exists in referenceDetails dataset otherwise as invalid details at once

I tried to do inner join and left_anti join. But i have to join twice. Is there any way to avoid join twice

```
  val invalidRecords = detailsDS.join(referencedetailsDS,Seq(Code),"left_anti")


val invalidRecords = detailsDS.join(referencedetailsDS,Seq(Code),"inner")

 Valid Details


#code    date   location temperature


    1     1-1-19    blr      30


    2     1-2-18  up       33

 Invalid Details

code    date   location temperature

    3     1-2-18  dlh      25
```

Comment: Invalid details can be subtracted from details with "except" method for get valid.

Comment: For except method schemas of both dataset should be same. details and active details have different schemas

Comment: For "except" you can select only required columns from wide dataframe.

Comment: I require all the columns from wider dataframe , i cannot select few columns and execute except()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with left join:

```
// data
val details = Seq(
  (1, "1-1-19", "blr", 30),
  (2, "1-2-18", "up", 33),
  (3, "1-2-18", "dlh", 25)
).toDF("code", "date", "location", "temperature")

val refrenceDetails = Seq(
  (1, "1-1-19", "blr"),
  (2, "1-2-18", "up")).
  toDF("code", "date", "location")

// action
val joined = details.alias("d").join(refrenceDetails.alias("r"), Seq("code"), "left")
val validDetails = joined.where($"r.code".isNotNull)
val invalidDetails = joined.where($"r.code".isNull)

// display
validDetails.show(false)
invalidDetails.show(false)
```

Output:

```
+----+------+--------+-----------+------+--------+
|code|date  |location|temperature|date  |location|
+----+------+--------+-----------+------+--------+
|1   |1-1-19|blr     |30         |1-1-19|blr     |
|2   |1-2-18|up      |33         |1-2-18|up      |
+----+------+--------+-----------+------+--------+

+----+------+--------+-----------+----+--------+
|code|date  |location|temperature|date|location|
+----+------+--------+-----------+----+--------+
|3   |1-2-18|dlh     |25         |null|null    |
+----+------+--------+-----------+----+--------+
```